# Codeigniter 4 /CI4/ Using database to keep site configurations/ How to make key and value accessible globally

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have a database that holds several basis configuration settings for my site.  The idea is to pull the values from the database and then make the values accessible globally.  I also would like to implement `$this->cachePage(DAY);` to make sure the site is not constantly asking for configurations settings.

This is mysql table
[image: app_setting table]

I have put the following code into `public function initController` method of the
BaseController:

```
    $global_app_settings = array();
    
    $this->AppSettingModel        = new \App\Models\AppSettingModel;    
    
    $app_settings = $this->AppSettingModel->getAppSettings();
    
    foreach ($app_settings as $row) {
        $global_app_settings[$row->app_setting_key] = $row->app_setting_value;
    }
```

The above code works fine.  If I print to screen, it produces the following;

```
Array
(
[dh_company_name] => A Big Company
[dh_phone_number] => +81-3-5555-5555
[dh_fax_number] => +81-3-5555-5556
)
```

My questions are as follows;

- how can I make the array viable globally in my app?
- Where can I add this?  `$this->cachePage(DAY);`

Comment: ok, half of it, I figured out.  $this->global_app_settings and extend the class.  So, just now sure on where to add the cachePage();  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple actually.

```
public function loadGlobalSettings()
{
    $globalSettings = cache('global_settings');

    if (null === $globalSettings) {
        $appSettingModel = model('\App\Models\AppSettingModel');
        
        $app_settings = $appSettingModel->getAppSettings();
        $globalSettings = [];
    
        foreach ($app_settings as $row) {
            $globalSettings[$row->app_setting_key] = $row->app_setting_value;
        }
        
        cache()->save('global_settings', $globalSettings, DAY*15);
    }

    return $globalSettings;
}
```

How it runs:

1. Try to get from cache.
2. If cache not exists (returned null), load model, get settings, then cache it.
3. Return settings array.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks!  That works very well.  One additional question.  I read on the CI man pages that to access the cached data like this;$foo = $cache->get('my_cached_item');

I put call  $this->global_settings = $this->loadGlobalSettings(); in the initController in the BaseController.  That mean I can call  echo $this->global_settings['dh_company_name']; anywhere.... but should I be using   $cache->get()?  I cannot seem to figure out how to call it properly.  Thank you!

Comment: You can access in three ways: 1. Inside method, `$foo = cache()->get('bar')`.   2. Inside method, `$cache = service('cache'); $foo = $cache->get('bar')`.    3. In class constructor, `$this->cache = service('cache');` then inside method `$foo = $this->cache->get('bar')`.   In summary first decide how to load cache service :)

Comment: So I should be able to access like this;  $foo = cache()->get('dh_company_name') ?

Comment: But I cannot.  Would I have to save each setting as a key in this?  cache()->save('dh_company_name', 'a big company', DAY*15);?

Comment: ah, ok, so I changed to  cache()->save($row->app_setting_key, $row->app_setting_value, DAY*15) and then I can use $foo = cache()->get('dh_company_name') etc.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Define a protected variable in `BaseController` class and set it in `initController`

Put this in your controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    this->cachePage(15);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ergec.  That will cache everything I think. I just want to cache the $this->global_site_settings  I came across this code;  if (! $foo = cache('foo')) {
    echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
    $foo = 'foobarbaz!';

    // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
    cache()->save('foo', $foo, 300);
}

echo $foo;

... but i don't understand this logic .. ! $foo = cache('foo')  ... I thought = makes $foo the same as cache('foo') on the right.  I think this code made help but cannot understand it yet.  Thanks.

Comment: you asked how to implement `cachePage` thats why i give this example. If you need to cache something specific then you can use `Caching Driver` https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html